# How to read xml column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an xml script in a customer table. Below structure is the Structure I need it in table for

```html
<pricer xmlns="http://www.Card.com/xxxx/xxxx">
  <service>
    <response>
      <businessObjectModel>
        <Id>0</Id>
        <Card xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Card">
          <ID>1</ID>
          <Inc>0.0</Inc>
          <value>0.0</value>
          <Tvalue1>0.0</Tvalue1>
        </Card>
      </businessObjectModel>
```

I need like below table:

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate Card's you can do it like this:

```
   DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '
<pricer xmlns:xsi="http://www.Card.com/xxxx/xxxx">
  <service>
    <response>
      <businessObjectModel>
        <Id>0</Id>
        <Card xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Card">
          <ID>1</ID>
          <Inc>0.0</Inc>
          <value>0.0</value>
          <Tvalue1>0.0</Tvalue1>
        </Card>
      </businessObjectModel>
      <businessObjectModel>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Card xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Card">
          <ID>1</ID>
          <Inc>2.0</Inc>
          <value>1.0</value>
          <Tvalue1>2.0</Tvalue1>
        </Card>
      </businessObjectModel>
      </response></service></pricer>'

SELECT   
Tbl.Col.value('ID[1]', 'int'),
Tbl.Col.value('Inc[1]', 'decimal'),
Tbl.Col.value('value[1]', 'decimal'),
Tbl.Col.value('Tvalue1[1]', 'decimal')
FROM   @XML.nodes('pricer/service/response/businessObjectModel/Card') Tbl(Col)
GO
```

Comment: i can not system will generate in above format only .